# Should I cancel our appointment with the repair tech for our washing machine?

Tags: repair, washing-machine

I have a 6 1/2 months old washing machine. Last week, we started having issues it. It would drain some of the water out, but not all of it. It also made a horrible racket all the way through the cycle. It was a continuous fast clicking sound. We unplugged it and did not use it for a whole week. The repair tech is supposed to come today, so, I tried plugging it back in and testing it last night.

I don't know what happened while it was unplugged, but the thing drained all of the water out, so that part of it seems to have corrected itself. What I am still worried about is that even though it is not pronounced, I can still hear a continuous fast clicking noise as it goes through its cycle, especially in the spin cycle, and it shakes and shimmies while it is going through the spin cycle despite being self balancing.

Should we keep our appointment with the repair tech or is there something we can do to repair it? Or is it normal for it to be shaking and shimmying like it is?

Comment: Please take a look through the other [tag:washing-machine] questions on the site; some of them may help you troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: Actually 6 1/2 months isn't long at all. What kind of warranty do you have? Could the repair be covered under warranty? If so let them do it.

Answer (score 1):

The first (and easiest) two things to check are:

1. **Drainage hose**  - Inspect for kinks or other obstructions.  Measure the max height of the pipe and verify via the manual that it is within acceptable limits.
2. **Machine Level** - With a long level, check the machine front-to-back and side-to-side for level.  Adjust the feet to correct as necessary.  Even if level, ensure all of the feet are making solid contact with the floor.